# Проверка электронной подписи в Java

Tags: java, криптография, валидация, цифровая-подпись

В подписях и криптографии я новичок, поэтому заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос покажется глупым. В общем есть подпись в формате p7s (signedData) и есть файл (pdf), который к этой подписи относится. Необходимо проверить соответствие подписи к файлу. Моя проверка заключалась исключительно в том, что массив байт подписи перегонялся в ASN.1 и оттуда ужаснейшим образом(другого ничего в голову не пришло) проверялось соответствие значений определенных полей (Object Identifier) к имени автора. Библиотека - Bouncy Castle

Вот код

```
String rawString = ASN1ObjectIdentifier.fromByteArray(bytesArray).toString();

String rawStringForSurname = rawString.substring(rawString.indexOf("2.5.4.4,") + 9, rawString.length());
String signSurname = rawStringForSurname.substring(0, rawStringForSurname.indexOf("]"));


String rawStringForGivenName = rawString.substring(rawString.indexOf("2.5.4.42,") + 10, rawString.length());
String signGivenName = rawStringForGivenName.substring(0, rawStringForGivenName.indexOf("]"));
```

Выглядит очень плохо. Для меня было очень удивительно, что помимо этого необходимо проверять еще дату(но это хотя бы можно вытащить из ASN) и сам hash (или другую уникальную информацию, которая и "привязывает" подпись к файлу, которую неизвестно откуда взять). В общем на входе мы имеем сам файл, файл подписи ну и еще имя автора, которое сравнивается кодом выше. Вопрос: Как вообще проверять соответствие? Какие данные брать из подписи и файла? Можно ли это сделать при помощи Bouncy Castle. По поводу алгоритма хеширования используется -
ГОСТ Р 34.11/34.10-2001, алгоритм шифрования - ГОСТ Р 34.11-94(знать бы еще чем отличаются).

Comment: Алгоритмы отличаются тем, что один - алгоритм хэширования, другой - шифрования.

Comment: Это, конечно, замечательно, но какой используется при проверке подписи принадлежности документу?

Comment: Вы не поверите, на для подписывания и проверки используется И хэширование, И шифрование этого хэша.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, как происходит проверка? Хотя бы в двух словах, мне бы понять куда копать

Comment: Берется подпись, расшифровывается публичным ключом (если сделано на асимметричной криптографии), получается хэш. И этот хэш нужно сравнить с хэшом данных. Если равны - подпись валидна.

Comment: А нужно ли мне вообще перегонять файл подписи в ASN.1, для того, чтобы получить значения определенных атрибутов по объектному идентификатору? Перегонять все в строку и потом получать другие строки таким образом как у меня, мне кажется, нельзя.

Comment: А тут все зависит от используемых библиотек, функций и деталей реализации...

Comment: Зачем вы парсите PKCS7 файл ASN1 парсером, если BouncyCastle имеет поддержку этого формата? Можете посмотреть мой ответ здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745489/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java-bouncy-castle

Answer (score 1):

Пример на p7s файле с RSA сертификатом/подписью:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.p7s"));
data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);

// парсим массив байт
CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(data);
// получаем список сертификатов, которые содержатся в файле
Store<X509CertificateHolder> certs = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();

// p7s файл может содержать данные, которые были подписаны, то есть ваш pdf файл
byte[] content = (byte[])cmsSignedData.getSignedContent().getContent();

// проходимся по списку подписей, обычно одна подпись, но стандарт поддерживает множество подписей
for (SignerInformation si: cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos())
{
    // список всех атрибутов, подписанных вместе с файлом
    AttributeTable signedAttributes = si.getSignedAttributes();
    // атрибут с именем
    Attribute attrSurname = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.4.4"));
    // атрибут с именем 2
    Attribute attrGivenName = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.4.42"));
    // атрибут с датой подписи
    Attribute attrSigningTime = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.5"));
    // выводим дату подписи
    System.out.println(attrSigningTime.getAttributeValues()[0].toString());

    // возможно некоторые атрибуты не были частью подписи, формат поддерживает и такие
    //AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = si.getUnsignedAttributes();

    // получаем идентификатор сертификата, которым подписаны данные
    SignerId signerId = si.getSID();
    // ищем сертификат в коллекции по идентификатору
    Collection certCollection = certs.getMatches(signerId);
    // выбираем первый сертификат, здесь не должно быть больше одного
    Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
    // создаем Verifier на основании сертификата, Verifier использует публичный ключ сертификата
    SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder);
    // проверяем подпись
    boolean signatureOK = si.verify(verifier);
    System.out.println(signatureOK);
}
```

Сам файл в base64:

```
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
```