# Проверка электронной подписи в Java Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, криптография, хеширование, цифровая-подпись

На входе у меня 2 файла, файл p7s и файл, который был этой подписью подписан. Вопрос заключается в том, как можно проверить данные? Судя по всему, сначала мы берем файл, применяем алгоритм хэширования(в данном случае ГОСТ Р 34.11-94) через Bouncy Castle получаем хэш, который впоследствии должен быть сравнен. А что мы делаем с файлом подписи? Слышал, что нужно брать публичный ключ(откуда?), который расшифровывает файл подписи(как?) по другому алгоритму(ГОСТ Р 34.11/34.10-2001) и в конце концов возвращает хэш. Как это все выглядит на практике? Поправьте меня, если я не прав по поводу последовательности действий.

Answer (score 1):

p7s-файл это PKCS7 хранилище данных. В него есть определенная структура:

- Указан хеш-алгоритм, который применялся над изначальными данными, которые подписываются
- Сама подпись в виде бинарных данных
- X509 сертификаты. В них находятся публичные ключи, которые используются для проверки подписи

> Слышал, что нужно брать публичный ключ(откуда?), который расшифровывает файл подписи(как?)

Про публичный ключ я написал выше. Неправильно говорить, расшифровывает файл подписи. В PKCS7 файле ничего не зашифровано. А проверка подписи, это просто функция `ValidateSignature(message, signature, publicKey)`, которая возвращает `true/false`.

> Судя по всему, сначала мы берем файл, применяем алгоритм хэширования(в данном случае ГОСТ Р 34.11-94) через Bouncy Castle получаем хэш, который впоследствии должен быть сравнен

PKCS7 может содержать хеш подписанного сообщения, а может и не содержать. В зависимости от этого, вы сравниваете их.

Пример кода проверки подписи:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.p7s"));
data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);

// парсим массив байт
CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(data);
// получаем список сертификатов, которые содержатся в файле
Store<X509CertificateHolder> certs = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();

// проходимся по списку подписей, обычно одна подпись, но стандарт поддерживает множество подписей
for (SignerInformation si: cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos())
{
    // получаем идентификатор сертификата, которым подписаны данные
    SignerId signerId = si.getSID();
    // ищем сертификат в коллекции по идентификатору
    Collection certCollection = certs.getMatches(signerId);
    // выбираем первый сертификат, здесь не должно быть больше одного
    Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
    // создаем Verifier на основании сертификата, Verifier использует публичный ключ сертификата
    SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder);
    // проверяем подпись
    boolean signatureOK = si.verify(verifier);
    System.out.println(signatureOK);
}
```

Пример файла с подписью и RSA-сертификатом:

```
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
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ. Хотя бы понял куда копать. И все хочу прояснить:
1. Хеш-алгоритм, который указан в подписи нужен для того, чтобы потом прогнать оригинальный файл(предварительно переведенный в base64) именно по нему?
2. Подпись - это у нас подпись чего? Самого файла? Прогнал через ASN.1, нашел что-то типо 512 gostSignature с нулями и единичками, наверное, она
3. X509 сертификаты я научился обрабатывать, находить нужную информацию. Есть публичный ключ. Что с ним дальше делать? 
Понять бы полный порядок действий. Заранее спасибо

Comment: 1. Да, верно. Только не нужно переганять в base64, обычно вычисляют хеш напрямую. 2. Обычно это подпись всего файла. 3. Вам не нужно разбираться с публичными ключами, классы BouncyCastle сделают это за вас. В примере кода сделано именно так, через класс `PKCS7SignedData`.

Comment: Да вот незадача - этот класс выпилили из BC

Comment: Есть `CMSSignedData`, который тоже работает с PKCS7 форматом.

Comment: Вот именно его я и использую. Но он мне помогает только брать необходимые атрибуты по objectIdentifier'у, работать с сертификатами. Там нет волшебного метода update, который берет массив байт в параметры. И verify там тоже нет :(

Comment: Я добавил пример кода для последней версии Bouncy Castle