# Проверки электронной подписи ЕСИА openId

Tags: java, oauth2, сертификат, openid, есиа

Добрый день! Пишу интеграцию с есиа по opendid connect на java. Назрел вопрос по проверки подписи маркера доступа/идентификации. Вкратце что сказано в методических указания по поводу проверки подписи:

Маркер доступа/идентификации выглядит как HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE в формате Base64Url. SIGNATURE представляет собой подпись в формате PKCS#7 detached
signature в кодировке UTF-8 от значений первых двух частей маркера доступа
(HEADER.PAYLOAD). Необходимо осуществить проверку данной электронной подписи
с использованием сертификата ключа проверки электронной подписи ЕСИА.

Собственно сами вопросы:

Как сделать эту проверку подписи если есть только сама подпись строки(signature) и сама строка которую подписывали (header.payload)?

Откуда взять сертификата ключа проверки электронной подписи ЕСИА (Видел подобный вопрос на stackoverflow но ответов нет)?

Или может эта часть signature имеет в себе какие-то данные сертификата и ключа, и можно как то проверить? если да то как это сделать?

Comment: PKCS#7 может содержать внутри себя сертификаты. Можете посмотреть мой ответ здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744975/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java

Comment: @Zergatul У меня не файл а просто строка, ну это не важно. То есть она содержит в себе то что подписывает? А зачем тогда нужна информация о том что она подписывает? ее наверное не просто так присылают. И другой вопрос а в чем смыл тогда проверки подписи заключается? Есть подпись в формате pkcs#7 мы оттуда вытаскиваем сертификат и верификатор и проверяем, непонятно ничего, зачем самого себя проверяем?

Comment: Формат PKCS#7 может содержать внутри данные, которые он подписал, а может и не содержать. Я не уверен, возможно `detached signature` как раз и значит, что самих данных внутри нет. Вы должны проверить в себя, доверяете вы этому сертификату, или нет. В этом суть проверки подписи. И это вы уже делаете, как хотите. Или проверяете в локальном хранилище доверенных сертификатов, или хардкодите серийный номер сертификата/SHA-1 отпечаток.

Comment: @Zergatul проблема в отсутствии сертификата. Есть подпись - массив из 256 байт, там сертификата нет. По адресу https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/idp/shibboleth сертификат не подходит.

Comment: @Zergatul Вот сейчас не понял на счет проверки в локальном хранилище сертификата или серийный номер sha1. Как бы самого сертификата и ключей есиа не предоставляет которым он подписывает. Но я читал что pkcs#7 содержит в себе сертификат с публичным ключом. Написал код в мои ответах есть, но я не знаю является ли это правильным.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял что pkcs7 хранит в себе сертификат, и просто этим сертификатом проверяешь эту подпись(то есть себя ж), возможно я что-то я понял не так..
Вот код:

```
public boolean verify(byte[] data) {
    try {
        CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(data);
        // получаем список сертификатов, которые содержатся в файле
        Store<X509CertificateHolder> certs = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();
        // p7s файл может содержать данные, которые были подписаны, то есть ваш pdf файл
        byte[] content = (byte[]) cmsSignedData.getSignedContent().getContent();
        // проходимся по списку подписей, обычно одна подпись, но стандарт поддерживает множество подписей

        for (SignerInformation si : cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos()) {
            // список всех атрибутов, подписанных вместе с файлом
            AttributeTable signedAttributes = si.getSignedAttributes();
            // атрибут с именем
            Attribute attrSurname = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.4.4"));
            // атрибут с именем 2
            Attribute attrGivenName = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.4.42"));
            // атрибут с датой подписи
            Attribute attrSigningTime = signedAttributes.get(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.5"));
            // выводим дату подписи
            System.out.println(attrSigningTime.getAttributeValues()[0].toString());

            // возможно некоторые атрибуты не были частью подписи, формат поддерживает и такие
            //AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = si.getUnsignedAttributes();

            // получаем идентификатор сертификата, которым подписаны данные
            SignerId signerId = si.getSID();
            // ищем сертификат в коллекции по идентификатору
            Collection certCollection = certs.getMatches(signerId);
            // выбираем первый сертификат, здесь не должно быть больше одного
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            // создаем Verifier на основании сертификата, Verifier использует публичный ключ сертификата
            SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certHolder);
            // проверяем подпись
            return si.verify(verifier);
        }
    } catch (CertificateException | OperatorCreationException | CMSException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Как я понял byte[] content может не содержать самих данных которые подписывает а может и содержать. Так же  Attribute *** написаны чисто для проверки. И еще маркер состоит из header.payload.signature в формате base64url, поэтому signature надо декодировать примерно так:

```
 byte[] data = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(a);
```

И уже эту data надо отправлять в эту функцию public boolean verify(byte[] data). Возможно это решение не верное, я точно не знаю. Если это правильно/неправильно то напишите что все ок или подскажите как правильно.

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно конструктор `CMSSignedData` умеет определять base64 и сам его декодирует. Это легко проверяется. Если PKCS7 не содержит внутри себя данных, которые он подписывает, он содержит их хеш, вы должны сверить этот хеш, с хешом от ваших данных, что бы удостоверится, что подпись действительно подписала то, что нужно (а не какие-то левые данные).

Comment: @Zergatul Как достать хэш из pkcs7? второй вопрос как достать хэш из того что он подписал не зная хэш функции:
он подписывает такую штуку-header.payload и header и payload находятся в формате base64 но соединены через точку. Все очень сложно и ничего непонятно..

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, хэш будет среди `signedAttributes`. Если есть возможность, прикрепите пример ваших данных вместе с подписью. На живом примере будет легче разобраться. Где-то внутри PKCS7 указано, какая хеш-функция используется (при помощи ASN1 object identifier)